# Attaching images to dhtmlx window

Tags: javascript, json, loops, dhtmlx

I have created a dhtmlx window using the code below:

```
    self.w_pictures = new dhtmlXWindows();
    self.w_pictures.enableAutoViewport(false);
    self.w_pictures.attachViewportTo(vp);

    uid = "about_pictures";
    self.w_pictures[uid] = self.w_pictures.createWindow('Win' + uid, "", "", 900, 600);

    var pos = self.w_pictures[uid].getPosition();


    self.w_pictures[uid].setModal(true);

    self.w_pictures[uid].button('park').hide();
    self.w_pictures[uid].denyMove();
    self.w_pictures[uid].denyResize();
    self.w_pictures[uid].setText('');
    var offset = (document.body.scrollTop ? document.body.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset);
    self.w_pictures[uid].setPosition(((window.innerWidth) / 2 - 450), offset);
```

Then I have to attach some images as gallery to the created window. How come it possible?
I supposed to add images which paths are from the json response. Since i am new to this dhtmlx please somebody help me out form here

Answer (score 1):

You can use dhtmlxDataView or new cool dhtmlxCarousel components
You can read about them by links:
[DataView](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxDataView/) and [Carousel](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCarousel/)